# laravel remember database connection per class

Tags: database, laravel, laravel-4

```
class DogsConfigs extends DogsModel {

protected $table = 'configs';


/**
 * @return 
 */
public function getAll() {
    return DB::connection($this->connection)    
        ->table($this->table)   
        ->select('conf_key', 'conf_val', 'description')
        ->get();
}
```

}

For every functiuon which uses non default database connection - I have to call DB::connection

I know this connections is used for whole class. How could I make it default for that class so I would not need to repeat code? Same for table.

Tried to google for solutions, but what I found - does not work.

Answer (score 0):

In your model you can define the connection you want to use:

```
 protected $connection = 'connection_name';
```

The connection you use must be in your  `app/config/database.php`

You can read this for more informations : http://fideloper.com/laravel-multiple-database-connections

Comment: This does not work for me. Tried extending directly Eloquent Class instead of DogsModel but same. Such connection is in database.php, otherwise it would not work with DB::connection also.